# URL Rewrite issue after login

Tags: php, .htaccess

I succesfully managed to add to my url an parameter but I can't redirect to the other pages. For example, if I click on logout it's not working even if I have a redirect rule added.

```
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&lang=en [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^ro/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&lang=ro [NC,L]
RewriteRule acasa$ index.php?page=acasa&lang=ro&params=$1&params1=$ [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ index.php?page=acasa [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)(?:/([0-9a-zA-Z]+))?/?$ index.php?page=acasa&params=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)(?:/([0-9a-zA-Z]+))(?:/([0-9]*))?/?$ index.php?page=acasa&params=$1&params1=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule logout$ index.php?page=logout [NC,L]
```

And here it's the PHP code:

```
   <?php

// Includere clasa login
include_once("class/class_login.php");

// Reseteaza login (delogare)
$login = new Login($db);
$login->_logout();

// remove 'remember me' cookie
if(isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]))
{
    setcookie ($cookie_name, '', time() - $cookie_time);
}
unset($_SESSION[PRE.'cookie']);

header("Location: " . $BASE, TRUE, 301);
exit();

?>
```

This is how the page it's looking like. If I click on logout it's not redirecting me to the logout page anymore... Here are some screenshots: 
[image]

[image: After I press the logout button, the logout function it's not working anymore]

Comment: Sorry, unclear what you are asking. You say you have one RewriteRule that tries to match `acasa$` - and now you are showing us a screenshot with a totally different letter combination at the end of the URL? No, `OTadM...` does not match that, no. But what is your actual question regarding that now …?

Comment: @CBroe I edited my question, I hope now I'm clear

Comment: If you mean this `RewriteCond` set for each `RewriteRule`, then this set must precede each `RewriteRule`.

Comment: Thanks @Deadooshka, it finally worked!